# To create Microsoft Graph apps, you have to have an Azure Subscription?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-active-directory

I have a test office 365 install to run some sample queries against Microsoft Graph.
Part of the authentication flow outlined [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service/), describes getting the tenant ID from Azure AD. To get your tenant ID you have to go through manage.windowsazure.com according to the [guidance provided](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-your-Office-365-tenant-ID-6891b561-a52d-4ade-9f39-b492285e2c9b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). 
So, is it that to build these MS graph apps, you have to provision an Azure Subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't have to provision an Azure Subscription. The the tenant ID from Azure AD is referenced because I guess 'behind scenes' office 365 is on Azure, its authentication based on Azure AD, etc.

Comment: Correct, you don't need an Azure subscription. Please see the guidance here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/auth_overview

Answer (score 0):

You can create application in https://portal.azure.com, even if you don't have azure ad subscription.

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks